# What is the minimum security role required to be able to query ML via ODBC

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, roles, marklogic-10

I am trying to set up a dedicated user in ML for SQL query via ODBC.
What is the minimum acccess role required?

It works well if I assign the user with the default admin role.
However if I give only sql-execution role, I could use that user to connect to ODBC but the query will return zero record.

```
{
"user-name" : "AppBI",
"description" : "SQL Query User - Read Only",
"password" : "password1",
"role" : [ "sql-execution" ]  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been **resolved**.

The **sql-execution** role is required to run ODBC query.
The black/zero record from the query was due to no read access on that TDE and content DB. The solution is to grant that AppBI user with **myApp-internal** role.

`{ "user-name" : "AppBI", "description" : "SQL Query User - Read Only", "password" : "password1", "role" : [ "sql-execution", "myApp-internal" ] }`

Default roles created by using `gradlew -i mlNewProject`

[image: Default roles created by using mlNewProject]